# Could not connect to my sql using php ,undefined function mysql_connect()

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile, php-ini, php

i want to open a connection to `mysql` database using php with following code:

`$connection= mysql_connect("localhost","m****","******");`

but I've got `undefined function mysql_connect()`

i checked out my `phpinfo()` and got this:
[image: phpinfo()]

so i tried to turn on `mysqli.allow_local_infile` so i do following in `php.ini` file:
`mysqli.allow_local_infile = On`

and tried to restart `apache2` and `mysql` services but does not effect.

what should i do? thanks in advance,

I'm   using `Ubuntu 18.4` with `php 7.2.24` and `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.28`

Comment: Some answers imply that the function was renamed, which is totally misleading. The whole extension was abandoned and it was eventually removed **several years ago**. You need to rewrite your app to use a currently available extension such as PDO or mysqli.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your function name from `mysql_connect` to `mysqli_connect` as `mysql_` is not supported in PHP7.x

further, you need to use all functions having `mysqli_` instead of `mysql_`

For more guidance: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 1):

`mysql` not supported in PHP 7 so you can use `mysqli`.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 1):

use `mysqli_connect` instead of `mysqli_connect`

```
$connection= mysqli_connect("localhost","m****","******");
```

Comment: Hope its Work!!!!!>

Comment: please select this answer if its help for you THANK YOU@mostafa jamareh.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working with legacy code, it's possible to install the MySQL extension in PHP 7 if you really need it, but it's deprecated and removed in PHP 7, but still possible to compile PHP to include it, although a pain to achieve. Either way, best to rewrite code to use either MySQLi or PDO instead.

If you don't have the time to do refactoring, and don't have the time to get the deprecated and removed MySQL extension into PHP, you can also try using code that emulates the MySQL extension using the MySQLi extension:
https://github.com/e-sites/php-mysql-mysqli-wrapper
https://github.com/kijin/mysql-compat
I've used such code before in the past in conjunction with `auto_prepend_file` to get a whole legacy codebase onto PHP 7 without spending much time refactoring code lacking tests, etc. The idea behind doing it with auto_prepend_file is in case the legacy code has multiple entry points to save you from editing several files in the codebase so it's always available. One drawback of such approaches is that code which explicitly checks for the MySQL extension to be loaded will fail to detect the extension, such has been my experience with certain Wordpress versions.

All that said, if you lack the time, try to convince whoever you're working for, or yourself, that it's worthwhile swapping over to either MySQLi or PDO and taking the time to refactor code, etc.